# Adler32 and MD4 for checksums

Tags: hash, checksum

Which algorithm does provide safer "speedy checksums"? Choose only from `MD4` and `Adler32`.

Comment: Why should I only choose from those? I wouldn't ever use them. Is this a test question?

Comment: @Chris: Why wouldn't you use those hash functions?

Comment: The possibility of collisions, for one.

Comment: It depends on the types of errors you can expect, as each checksum algorithm has a different class of errors that it cannot detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use both of them for checksums. As both are "relatively speedy", you can't be more safe than use both - ancient - options.

However, if you are looking for the safest option -- I'd say MD4.

Quote:

> In the original SWID requirements, the acceptable collision rate was
>   determined at 1 in 10 million. The degree of uniqueness here is
>   important, but it does not have to be as robust as MD4's claim of 2^64
>   operations before a collision may occur.

Source: [MD4-SWID.pdf](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~djr/ics125/s99-projects/MD4-SWID.pdf)

For short messages, Adler32 has a weakness to be aware of:

> Jonathan Stone discovered in 2001 that Adler-32 has a weakness for
>   very short messages. He wrote "Briefly, the problem is that, for very
>   short packets, Adler32 is guaranteed to give poor coverage of the
>   available bits. Don't take my word for it, ask Mark Adler. :-)" The
>   problem is that sum A does not wrap for short messages. The maximum
>   value of A for a 128-byte message is 32640, which is below the value
>   65521 used by the modulo operation. An extended explanation can be
>   found in RFC 3309, which mandates the use of CRC32 instead of Adler-32
>   for SCTP, the Stream Control Transmission Protocol.

and:

> Running Adler, CRC32 and both on several sets of 1 million randomly
>   generated url-like strings ranging from 16 to 128 characters in
>   length, Adler produced duplicates in ~1% of cases; CRC32 produced
>   ~0.2%; and in several runs the combination of both found just 2
>   duplicates (circa. 0.002% but not enough samples to be judged
>   representative).

Source: [Hashing urls with Adler32](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=618494)

Considering the chances of a collision are high [especially] with short messages using Alder32, MD4 has my vote.